# Wordpress Issues

Tags: wordpress, installation

I'm trying to install a WordPress theme, but it will not show the full page because I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_the_image() in /home/u629284378/public_html/1/wp-content/themes/Livosa/index.php on line 31
```

index.php line 31:

```
< ?php get_the_image( array( 'custom_key' => array( 'image' ), 'default_size' => 'thumbnail', 'width' => '180', 'height' => '150', 'image_class' => 'feature' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your theme depends on [Get the Image](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/get-the-image/) WordPress plugin. Install this plugin first, activate it and then try whatever you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, note the  `if ( function_exists`

Even though it's not your theme, it's best to use that construct:

```
 <?php if ( function_exists( 'get_the_image' ) ) get_the_image( array( 'custom_key'
 => array( 'image' ), 'default_size' => 'thumbnail', 'width' => '180', 'height' => '150',
 'image_class' => 'feature' ) ); ?>
```

in order to not throw an error when that plugin is not activated.